# How to move a doom element to the mouse position in a second regardless of their positions on the screen

Tags: javascript, css

https://codepen.io/DraguLL/pen/gOXmJgo hello everyone, how to change the code so that the square moves to the mouse position in exactly one second, no matter where it is and where the mouse position is

```js
  
    const myElement = document.getElementById('cir');
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

let xMouse = 0;
let yMouse = 0;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  xMouse = e.clientX;
  yMouse = e.clientY;
});


setInterval(() => {
      if (xMouse === x && yMouse === y) {
          x = xMouse;
          y = yMouse;
      } else {      
        if (xMouse > x) {
         x++;
        } else {
           x--;
        }
        if (yMouse > y) {
         y++;
        } else {
           y--;
        }
      }

      myElement.style.top = y + 'px';
      myElement.style.left = x + 'px';
  }, 1);
```

```css
.cir {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class ="cir" id = "cir"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout and then use CSS transition to make that smooth effect of red dot moving.

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById('cir');
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

let xMouse = 0;
let yMouse = 0;
let timer;
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  xMouse = e.clientX;
  yMouse = e.clientY;
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(mouseMove, 1000);
});

function mouseMove() {

          x = xMouse;
          y = yMouse;
      myElement.style.transition = "1s ease";
      myElement.style.top = y + 'px';
      myElement.style.left = x + 'px';

  }
```

```css
.cir {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class ="cir" id = "cir"></div>
```

Comment: No, I want the object to always move to the mouse position. What would, when getting a new mouse position, move there in one second, regardless of the distance between them.

Comment: Try to remove this line of code: `myElement.style.transition = "1s ease";` and run the code again to check if this is what you want? The object is moving to the position in exactly one second but due to the transition effect, you feel like it takes more time.